# Android Studio device preview without device frame has gone

Tags: android-studio, themes

I got the design file from GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-endpoints-helloendpoints-android project and made small changes. I changed the theme to a dark one. I don't know how this happened but I don't see the device controls or border/frame anymore. How can I reset it? Other design files are showing alright.

Finally found the reason. When I clicked on the black outer region of the preview window, a toolbar appears above it. First button on the left is called Toggle Viewport Render Mode. This brought back my device view.
[image: android studio device preview pane]

Answer (score 0):

Hhmm.. For me, whenever you design/designing your layout with the parent ScrollView Layout - it will not show the toolbar and the device frame.

To show your Scrollview layout to another layout you must include it. For example :

My ScrollView.xml

```
<ScrollView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:scrollbars="vertical"
android:fadeScrollbars="true"> </ScrollView>
```

**Include it in your activity_main.xml or other .xml file.**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context=".activities.ShareAppActivity">

<!--Include ActionBar/Toolbar-->
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:elevation="8dp"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary">
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    <include
        android:id="@+id/scrollview_layout"
        **layout="@layout/scrollview"**
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"/> </RelativeLayout>
```

Use the `<include />` - tag and in the layout="@layout/YOUR_XML_SCROLLVIEW"
in xml layout you wish to display/include your scrollview.
You can now see your scrollview_layout with device frame and toolbar.

Answer (score 0):

Click on preview window and press button 'F' on keyboard.